# Axios may ignore default headers

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I'm using axios in my nuxt project.
When I make a request by setting headers config in the request config, the default headers are ignored on node.js.

When I run the following code on node.js

```
import axios from "axios";
axios.defaults.headers.common["default-header"] = "default-header";
axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", {
  headers: { header1: "header1" },
})
.then((response) => {
  console.error(response.config);
});
```

The response config headers is as follows

```
  headers: {
    header1: 'header1'
  }
```

The expected response config headers is as follows

```
  headers: {
    default-header: "default-header"
    header1: "header1"
  }
```

When I run the following code on browser (like Chrome), response config headers is as expected.

Is this a bug in axios?

I created a repository for verification
https://github.com/mimi6612/nuxt-axios-request-config-sample

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the axios.create methode.

```
import axios from 'axios'

const requestHandler = config => {
  config.headers = {
      'defaultHeader': 'myDefaultHeaderString'
    }
  config.crossDomain = true
  return config
}

const requester = axios.create()
requester.interceptors.request.use(requestHandler)

export requester
```